# Javascript push into array - Performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, lodash

Consider we have 2 very large arrays of size N and M,

```
var array1 = [1,2,3...N],
    array2 = [a,b,c...M];
```

What's the most optimized way of pushing array2 into array1?

Using native JavaScript,

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(array1,array2)
```

Using Lodash,

```
array1 = _.concat(array1, array2)
```

As lodash makes copy of source array, I guess it's complexity would increase by O(N) as compare to native javascript.
Is there any other optimized way to push array? 
Also, why a hugely popular library like lodash doesn't provide option to modify existing array to improve performance?

Comment: As for lodash's feature, I suspect `_.concat` does not modify the existing array because the native `.concat` does not either.

Comment: (Off topic) but why would you even think about doing this `Array.prototype.push.apply(array1,array2)` on an array instance?, you only use the call or bind or apply functions when you need to "borrow" a function from the `Array.prototype` object to invoke on an **array-like** object like `arguments`. Simply just do `array1.concat(array2)`

Comment: @Dummy concat creates copy of source array and push doesn't create any copy and modify existing array, so performance of push should be better.

Comment: Look at the source...

Comment: I don't really understand why Lodash even provides a concat method, when it seems to do exactly the same thing as the native method.

Comment: @nnnnnn That's the case with many lodash functions, such as _.isArray if you see source code it's just var isArray = Array.isArray; Talking about array always reminds me millions of download for one line of code  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/isarray

Comment: Depending on how large the arrays and depending of the browser session the spread operator or apply method (which are basically the same) might yield a stack-overflow exception. In my experience you might expect it anytime your arrays are in the sizes larger than 150K items or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets make a simple test and see. When the array passed to push by apply as arguments, is large like 150K (in my current case it happens past 250076) you will notice the range error that i had mentioned in the comments. This is a major problem since for smaller arrays the performance difference is negligible anyways. So one should avoid using push with apply or spread operator if your array to be concatenated is large enough to make you concerned about the performance of the operation.

```js
function measureConcatPerformances() {
  var len = +arrayLength.value,
    ar1 = new Array(len).fill().map(e => ~~(Math.random() * 1000000)),
    ar2 = new Array(len).fill().map(e => ~~(Math.random() * 1000000)),
    ts = 0,
    te = 0;
  
  myError.textContent = "";
  ts = performance.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) ar1[ar1.length] = ar2[i];
  te = performance.now();
  forLoopResult.textContent = "ar1 and ar2 concataned in: " + (te - ts) + "msec by for loop";

  ar1 = new Array(len).fill().map(e => ~~(Math.random() * 1000000));
  ar2 = new Array(len).fill().map(e => ~~(Math.random() * 1000000));

  ts = performance.now();
  for (var val of ar2) ar1[ar1.length] = val;
  te = performance.now();
  forOfResult.textContent = "ar1 and ar2 concataned in: " + (te - ts) + "msec by for of loop";

  ar1 = new Array(len).fill().map(e => ~~(Math.random() * 1000000));
  ar2 = new Array(len).fill().map(e => ~~(Math.random() * 1000000));
  try{
  ts = performance.now();
  Array.prototype.push.apply(ar1, ar2);
  te = performance.now();
  applyResult.textContent = "ar1 and ar2 concataned in: " + (te - ts) + "msec by apply";
  } catch(err) {myError.textContent = "Error at apply: " + err}
  
  ar1 = new Array(len).fill().map(e => ~~(Math.random() * 1000000));
  ar2 = new Array(len).fill().map(e => ~~(Math.random() * 1000000));

  ts = performance.now();
  ar1 = ar1.concat(ar2);
  te = performance.now();
  concatResult.textContent = "ar1 and ar2 concataned in: " + (te - ts) + "msec by concat";
}

myButton.addEventListener("click", measureConcatPerformances);
```

```html
<input id="arrayLength" type="number" min="0" value = 0>
<button id="myButton">Length</button>
  <p id="forLoopResult"></p>
  <p id="forOfResult"></p>
  <p id="applyResult"></p>
  <p id="concatResult"></p>
  <p id="myError" style="color:red"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`push.apply(array1, array2)` is the most optimal since it modifies the reference of `array1`, but not copy/return it to be reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rest element` to collect elements of an array into another array; that is collect `array2` into `array1` when both arrays are created

```
var array1 = [...[1,2,3] ...(array2 = ["a", "b", "c"])];
```